# Azure Data Factory - How to Prevent malware import

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are using Azure Data Factory to import data into our OnPrem network via a Self Hosted Integration Runtime.

Our main concern about using Azure Data Factory is how to be able to prevent malware entering our On-Premise infrastructure.

Someone who is assigned the Contributor role for Azure Data Factory could easily import some malware through our Self Hosted Integration Runtime into our OnPremise network.
Our Network Administration wants to know if there could be taken some measurements to prevent this to keep the OnPremise infrastructure safe.

The best possibility to prevent malware entering our infrastructure would be on the SHIR because all data is passing through it from the cloud into OnPrem.

Questions:

1. Is there any possibility to virus scan the data stream passing through the SHIR ?
2. Do you see any other possibilities to restrict users from abusing ADF to import malware inside our OnPrem network ?

Thanks a lot to all for your support.

Comment: Why would malware enter? Are you importing raw binaries or scripts? Or emitting raw data into HTML pages?

Comment: Not sure I understand what the concern is, as the integration runtime isn't a generic gateway/vpn - it's a controlled agent, tied directly to. ADF and only has specific data movement actions. As for ADF permissions, you have the ability to limit who has access to your ADF instance. I'd suggest visiting the Microsoft Trust Center for more info on service security, and maybe reach out directly to one of the support channels if you have specific concerns. This question is unfortunately off-topic here (very broad and opinion-soliciting, on a non-programming question).